# mongoimport _id is not an ObjectId

Tags: json, database, mongodb

I'm working with MongoDB v3.6.4 on Windows 10

I have a JSON like:

```
[ {"_id": "5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec", "name": "Alfio"}, ... ]
```

I import it with:

```
mongoimport --db <mydb> --collection <mycollection> --file <myfile> --jsonArray
```

I get documents within my db in the correct location. BUT the _id is a plain string.

I can do all sort of queries, EXCEPT those queries which involve **_id** as search parameter, also **Model.findById()** doesn't work (it does not accept a string and not even an ObjectId).

Ids look like plain strings (**_id: "5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec"**), while in my other collections ids look like objects (_id: **ObjectId("5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec")**).

Why the import statement has imported everything without assigning ObjectId(s) instead of plain strings?

Why I cannot even query with something like the following?

```
Model.findOne({ _id: '5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec'})
```

What to do to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using this while importing on second collection , then both collection will have object id instead of _id

```
{ 
 "_id" : {"$oid":"5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec"}

}
```

Comment: I don't get it... What I have to do exactly?

Comment: modify your jsonarray into `[ {"_id": {"$oid":"5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec"}, "name": "Alfio"}, ... ]`

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: otherwise you have to run custom query after import like `db.Test.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { 
  var id = new ObjectId(myDoc._id);
  db.Test.remove(myDoc)
  myDoc._id=id;
  db.Test.save(myDoc)
   } );
`

Comment: Your first suggestion works well anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay. Anyway I'm not completely satisfied with the answer (even if it works) because it involves reformatting my exported JSON.